# Populate data from multi-dimensional object into ng-repeat list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I get the following data from a database in my ionic application. I am saving it to $scope.dbCustomersArray:

```
 [  
   {  
      "customer_id":1,
      "customer_name":"Test Company",
      "customer_address":"17 Morena Blvd Camarillo",
      "customer_city":"Ventura",
      "customer_contactnumber":"805-832-6163",
      "Company_id":1
   },
   {  
      "customer_id":2,
      "customer_name":"Another test company",
      "customer_address":"2742 Distribution Way Metairie",
      "customer_city":"Jefferson",
      "customer_contactnumber":"504-979-9175",
      "Company_id":1
   },
   {  
      "customer_id":3,
      "customer_name":"Final test company",
      "customer_address":"775 W 17th St San Antonio",
      "customer_city":"Bexar",
      "customer_contactnumber":"210-812-9597",
      "Company_id":1
   }
]
```

I am trying to loop through it in my html.

```
<label class="item item-input" style="padding: 0px">
                <div class="row">
                <label class="item item-input item-select col">
                    <div class="input-label" style="visibility: hidden">
                        Customer
                    </div>
                    <select>
                        <option> -- Customer -- </option>

                        <ion-item ng-repeat="customer in $scope.dbCustomersArray">
                           <option> Hello, {{customer.customer_name}}! </option>
                        </ion-item>

                    </select>

                </label>
                </div>
            </label>
```

I am returning no values and not getting any errors in my logs. I have tried to loop through $scope.dbCustomersArray using the following code, but the only values that are printed out are: `0`, `1` and `2` repspectively.

```
for (var customer in $scope.dbCustomersArray) {
     console.log("LOGGING A CUSTOMER - " + customer.customer_name);
}
```

Please help me with this problem. I don't see where I am going wrong. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I cant see the values in my array in my ionic application when I tap on the customers select list.

Comment: Remove the $scope from:
<ion-item ng-repeat="customer in $scope.dbCustomersArray">.
It's not a correct syntax

Comment: @MichaelZucchetta I did and tried to run the application again. There are no values from the array visible in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two problems:

1. You shouldn't be using $scope in your HTML.  Put only dbCustomerArray in your ng-repeat
2. I don't see your controller loaded in your HTML.  Somewhere you need ng-controller so it knows where to load the $scope data from

When you loop through your object array, 0, 1, 2 sounds accurate because those are your array indices.  I think confirming that your controller is loaded and removing $scope will correct your problems.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had a look at that myself, but it ended up not working. The values display fine when using `<ul><li><label ng-model="blah"></li></ul>`, but nothing displays with the code above.